# how do I grep within vim using some default parameters?

Tags: vim, grep

I often run a command such as this from within vim:

`:grep -r --exclude-dir=./.git --include=\*.cpp --include=\*.hpp .`

But I would like to not have to write this everytime I want to grep within vim, so I tried adding the following to my `.vimrc` file:

`command GrepRepo grep -r --exclude-dir=./build --exclude-dir=./.git --include=\*.cpp --include=\*.hpp .`

But then when I run `GrepRepo "STRING"` it just comes back blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this version of your command:

```
:command! -nargs=+ GrepRepo grep -r --exclude-dir=./build --exclude-dir=./.git --include=\*.cpp --include=\*.hpp . <args>
```